# Button save data in a .txt file and erase the old data in it

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, save

I managed to save my data (contained in an array called "test") in a .txt file when i click on the button "Export". My script creates a file each time i click on the button "Export".

My objective is that I want to save the data on every click, in the one and only file and I erase the old data that the text file had.

Thanks.

```
  <button type="button" id="bt" class="brk-btn" value="Exporter" onclick="saveFile()"> EXPORT </button>

  function saveFile(){
      let blob = new Blob([test]);
      let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      let file = document.createElement(`a`);
      file.download = `file.txt`;
      file.href = url;
      document.body.appendChild(file);
      file.click();
      file.remove();
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I see it right, the `file.txt` is downloaded by the browser.
If so you can not ovverwrite the file after the download, because the browser
will just rename it to file(1).txt

Comment: Yeah thats what actually happens.Is there anyway to create a file manually in my computer and erase the old data and replace it with the newest in each click ?